# What is the output ? How?

Tags: java

```
class B{
  B(){
    f();
  }
  public void f(){
    System.out.println("B ctor");
  }
}

class A extends B{
  A(){
    f();
  }

  @Override    
  public void f(){
    System.out.println("A ctor");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    a.f();
    B b = new B();
    b.f();
  }
}
```

The output of the above programs is

```
A ctor
A ctor
A ctor
B ctor
B ctor
```

Can any one please explain how did we get output.

Comment: What do you mean with "how did we get output?"

Comment: Why don't you explain what you expected and why - then we can work out where you're confused. Also, please fix the indentation - it's all over the place at the moment.

Comment: You should read up on inheritance, this is really basic stuff. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to visualize what happens by adding some more prints:

```
class B{
    B(){
        System.out.println("binit");
        f();
    }
    public void f(){
        System.out.println("B ctor");
    }
}

class A extends B{
    A(){
        System.out.println("ainit");
        f();
    }

    @Override
    public void f(){
        System.out.println("A ctor");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(1);
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(2);
        a.f();
        System.out.println(3);
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(4);
        b.f();
    }
}
```

Our output is now:

```
1
binit
A ctor
ainit
A ctor
2
A ctor
3
binit
B ctor
4
B ctor
```

So what's happening here? Between 1 and 2 we have two initialization, even though we have instantiated only A. This is because subclasses (A extends B) will, by default, call the superclass (B in this case) constructor as first thing on instantiation. And the constructor of B calls f(). But this f has been overriden by A, instead than printing "B ctor" will print "A ctor".
After that, the constructor of A runs, and prints "A ctor" by calling his own overrode f.

What happens after 2 is pretty straightforward. The only difference is that when we instantiate B (after 4), we are not using the overrode f, but the original one, so we print "B ctor".

Got it?

Comment: If this answer your question, you should mark the answer as the accepted one, by pressing the V tick to the left side of it :)